# SwiftUI: Disable ScrollView scrolling to top if top of screen is touched

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a UI which resides in a `VStack{}` with a custom topbar and a `ScrollView`. I have buttons on my top bar which do things like open user account details. I find that if I press some of these buttons the ScrollView autoscrolls to the top of the screen. Is there a way to stop that?

My code:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:0) {
            TopBarView()
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(String(index))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct TopBarView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("This is a top bar")
        }
    }
}
```

If I touch the top of the screen above the `scrollView`'s frame, the `scrollView` scrolls all the way to the top. Is there a way to disable that behavior?

[image: GIF showing the behavior]

Comment: I don't think I can understand how your code work with just these two lines of codes.

Comment: I'll add some more. 1 sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `SwiftUI` or `Xcode` or `ScrollView` problem.

This is a built-in feature of iPhone.

When you tap the top-center edge of the screen, displayed contents will be scrolled up.

Try opening apps like Facebook, WhatsApp, then scroll and tap at the same position, you will see the displayed contents scroll up.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to disable that?

Comment: what about ```.ignoresSafeArea()```?

Comment: @Randy this is likely about the iPhone accessibility rather than your programming code, so I don't think you can disable it. Also `.ignoreSafeArea()` won't work.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will have to move some of my menu buttons a bit farther away from the top to prevent the user clicking both them and the top at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

For `UIScrollView`, there's a [scrollsToTop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619421-scrollstotop) property you can disable:

```
let scrollview = UIScrollView()
scrollview.scrollsToTop = false
```

Nothing for SwiftUI's `ScrollView` as far as I can tell. You could use [UIViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) to wrap `UIScrollView` for SwiftUI.